# Put * before each line of comment in TypeScript file in VS Code IDE

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

I use VS Code and I want the comments that I write on several lines in Typescript language to be as follows (pay attention to the star character)

```
/**
 *@desc any text
 * any text
 */
```

But when I am writing a comment and I press enter, a star is not automatically created for the next line

```
/**
 *@desc any text
 any text
 */
```

So far, I have tested the following extensions on this date, but they did not solve this problem

> 1. Auto Comment Blocks
> 2. Comment Snippets
> 3. Better Comment
> 4. TSDoc Comment

Comment: This is JSDOC Comment, it shoul appear automatic when you write /**

Comment: Voting to reopen because this is not about commenting out an existing section of code, but rather about writing a new TSDoc-style comment from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed JavaScript Comment Snippet (Visual Studio Code)
extension
And I did the following steps

> Ctrl + Shift + P / ⇧ + ⌘ + P → Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)

And I set the following items in JSON file.

```
"editor.quickSuggestions": {
    "other": true,
    "comments": true,
    "strings": false
  },
```

And I restarted Visual Studio Code.

Now in your ts files your need write ///

Answer (score 3):

It works (for me) if you put a space after the star, which is common practice anyway:

```
/**
 * @desc any text<Enter>
 * 
 ^^ This star and space inserted automatically.
```

Answer (score 1):

Look in the preferences of VS Code and activate JSDOC

Comment: this is active in my vs code. but not work in typeScript files!